# Creating dynamic cucumber_steps to check for links on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, integration-testing, rspec2

Basically I want the scenario outline to loop through all of the various combinations so that I don't have to write a bunch of scenarios. I want to have it visit the starting page and then check to see if the links are there however I've hit a barrier.

**Cucumber feature**

```
    Scenario Outline: As a user I need links in order to navigate the site
    Given I am a '<user>'
    When I am at the <page> page
    Then I should see a link to '<link>'

    Scenarios: As a user that is not logged in
        |       user         |   page    |  link   |
        | not_signed_in_user |    /      | contact |
```

**Cucumber Feature Steps**

```
    Given /^I am a 'not_signed_in_user'$/ do
         @user = nil
    end

    When /^I am at the (.+) page$/ do |starting_page|
         visit starting_page
    end

    Then /^I should see a link to (.+)$/ do |link|
         pending
    end
```

I need to use something like:

```
    response.should have_selector('a,':href => link_path,
                                     :content => link )
```

but that won't work dynamically as it will just check for link_path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `send("#{link}_path")` here. That would generate the link using the routing helper which I think it is what you want.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I need, how would I use it though? link = send("#{link}_path") and then :href => link   ?

Comment: @Avc1298: yes, that's it. Try that.