# Ruby Cucumber Gmail Gem - how to click a link in email body

Tags: ruby, email, cucumber, mail-gem

I have searched the net upside down for this answer, but I can't seem to find it. I've tried various methods but they aren't working.

Goal: Using ruby cucumber, to click a link within an email I have received.
Seems simple right?

Using the gmail gem, something like:

```
When(/^I click the link$/) do
(insert code here)
```

I can get the body of the email back with

```
mail.inbox.emails(:from => "rubycucumber")do |email|
  puts email.html_part.body.decoded
end
```

But how do I navigate to/click the link (which is in A HREF tag when I view the email body after running step above)?

It seems the gmail gem is really awesome at counting, labeling, marking as read, etc, but this piece is giving me trouble :(

Comment: Look like you want to navigate a dynamically generated link. This answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810287/creating-dynamic-cucumber-steps-to-check-for-links-on-a-page